# does not contain shard key for pattern

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding

I'm trying to insert a document in a sharded collection but i'm getting :

> message='An upsert on a sharded collection must contain the shard key >and have the simple collation

I created the chard key :

```
config.shardCollection("key:{keyTime :1, software :1 name :1, code :1}")
```

and when a insert with :

```
db.getCollection('client').insert({
    "_id" : {
         "keyTime" : "dfsdf", "software" : "kjlkj", "name" : "kjljlk", "code" : "dsfdfsdf" 
    },
    "count" : NumberLong(17320)
})
```

I'm getting :

An upsert on a sharded collection must contain the shard key and have the simple collation

any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok finally adding  **hashed** worked

```
config.shardCollection("key:{keyTime :1, software :1 name :1, code :1}:hashed"")
```